# liquibase groovy foreign key constraint

Tags: grails, liquibase

Let's assume I've got tables

```
book
    id pk_id
    name


library
    book_id fk_book_id references book(id)
...
```

I want to add constraint with the name `fk_book_id` to `library` table, which is the foreign key, references to `id` field of the table `book`.
How to do that?

```
column(name:'book_id'...) {
    constraints { 
        nullable(false)
        unique(true)
    }
    constraints(foreignKeyName: 'fk_book_id', references: 'book' ... ) // column?
}
```

I know about `addForeignKeyContraint` method, but I'd like to use `constraints`. What is the syntax for it?